# C# code or algorithm to quickly calculate distance between large strings?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

Hi and thanks for looking!

## Background

I have an XML file that contains 1900 nodes which themselves contain a string of encoded data of about 3400 characters.

As part of a use case for an application I am developing, I need to be able to take a "benchmark" string at runtime, and find the *closest* match from the XML file.

Please note that XML is not germane to the app and that I may go with SQL moving forward, but for today, I just needed an easy place to store the data and prove the concept.

I am using .NET 4.0, C#, forms app, LINQ, etc.

## Question

How do I find the closest match?  Hamming?  Levenshtein?  There are plenty of code samples online, but most are geared towards small string comparisons ("ant" vs. "aunt") or exact match.  I will rarely have *exact* matches; I just need *closest* match.

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Comment: In order to solve this, you're going to have to define precisely what "closest" means for *you*.

Comment: This is more of a conceptual question, try programmers.se.  StackOverflow would be glad to help you with implementation details once you've picked an algorithm if you have problems getting it working (or performance problems).

Comment: @GregHewgill- Fair enough.  To me, this means that there is no other string in the data set that is closer.  I guess this would be similar to the result of a bubble sort.  Thanks.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: he surely meant the relative distance of the position in RAM.

Comment: @BenVoigt- Thanks, I will try that.  The only problem I have had in the past with programmers.se is that it doesn't have nearly the exposure as SO, therefore it is much harder to get the traction you can here.

Comment: I don't see how this isn't a valid question and I don't get the downvotes.  Basically OP is asking how to perform a Hamming distance computation or a Levenhstein Edit Distance computation on large strings or something similar to these algorithms (*i.e.* computing a distance).  Had he asked the same question for small strings this question would already crawl under answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned using *Levenhstein's Edit Distance* and that your strings were about 3400 characters long.

I did a quick try and using the *dynamic programming* version of Levenhstein's Edit Distance it seems to be quite fast and cause no issue.

I did this:

```
        final StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        final StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        final Random r = new Random(42);
        final int n = 3400;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sb1.append( (char) ('a' + r.nextInt(26)) );
            sb2.append( (char) ('a' + r.nextInt(26)) );
        }
        final long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("LED: " + getLevenshteinDistance(sb1.toString(), sb2.toString()) );
        final long te = System.currentTimeMillis() - t0;
        System.out.println("Took: " + te + " ms");
```

And it's finding the distance in 215 ms on a Core 2 Duo from 2006 or so.

Would that work for you?

*(btw I'm not sure I can paste the code for the DP LED implementation I've got here so you probably should search the Internet for one Java implementation)*

Comment: @user988052- EXCELLENT!  Thank you!  Is this the same "getLevenshteinDistance" method you are using: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/FindtheLevenshteindistancebetweentwoStrings.htm?

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: now that's funny...  Yes it's basically the same and that's the one you should use for large strings because it only initialize two arrays the length of the string, instead of matrix  of size *N x N* as can be seen in some (less memory efficient) DP LED ; )

Comment: This is hilarious--question closed as "not a real question" and "cannot be reasonably answered" when the answer above worked like a charm for me and has helped me progress in that area greatly.  Might be time to re-evaluate a few things boys ;).